# flash as3 call function in one child class from another child class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, singleton

I'm trying to call a function in one child class (Circle.as) from another child class (Wedge.as). Circle.as is instantiated by the document class (Tree.as), and Wedge.as is instantiated by Circle.as. How do I do this? This is my code:

Tree.as

```
package com.treediagram  
{  
  public class Tree extends MovieClip  
  {
    var firstCircle:Circle = new Circle();
    addChild(firstCircle);
  }
}
```

Circle.as:

```
package com.treediagram
{
  public class Circle extends MovieClip  
  {
    private var wedge:Wedge;
    public function Circle()  
    {
      var circleHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
      var circleClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
      circleClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,circleClickedEvent);
    }

    private function circleClickedEvent(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
      var wedgeHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
  circleHolderRef.addChildAt(wedgeHolder,1);
      var wedge:Wedge = new Wedge(wedgeHolderRef);
  wedge.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wedgeClickEvent);
    }



    private function wedgeClickEvent(e.target){
      trace ('click'); //NOT WORKING
    } 
  }
}
```

Wedge.as

```
package com.treediagram
{
  public class Wedge extends MovieClip  
  {
    public function Wedge(wedgeHolderRef)
    {
      var wedgeClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
      wedgeClip.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, wedgeAddedEvent);
      wedgeHolderRef.addChild(wedgeClip);
    }
  }
}
```

I saw a similar question to this here:

[How to call a function in a Class from another Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638537/how-to-call-a-function-in-a-class-from-another-class)

but it was a bit hard to follow as it relates to my problem. One of the solutions worked, but was commented as being bad form, and another did not work, so I want to make sure I structure my code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is OK for a parent class to know about its children, but not the other way around. If you don't follow this principle, you'll end up creating [Circular dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) and end up with code that is tightly coupled and hard to maintain. The key then is to prevent a child from needing to call its parent's methods directly.

One solution is to use [event-based communication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html). When something happens in the child class, it fires an event which a parent class may choose to handle or not.

For example:

```
public function Circle()  
{
  var wedge:Wedge = new Wedge();
  wedge.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onWedgeClick);
}
private function onWedgeClick(e:MouseEvent) {
  deactiveCircle();
}
```

Comment: You might want to dispatch a custom event from the Wedge class and capture that instead. So inside the "handleWedgeClick" function, just call "this.dispatchEvent(new Event("wedgeClick"));" And then listen for "wedgeClick" instead of MouseEvent.CLICK.

Comment: @panupan - the problem is I need to listen to the click of something inside of the wedge object, not wedge itself.

Comment: Hello, in that case you'll need to use event bubbling. This allows an event to actually "bubble up" through the view hierarchy. It's an implementation of the Responder Chain design pattern where a message gets passed along the chain (in this case a view hierarchy) giving an opportunity for each object to handle it before passing it on. Check out this simple example to get an idea: http://blog.152.org/2009/11/flash-actionscript-3-event-bubbling.html

Comment: Ah - that's the problem - I disabled bubbling (I think) with stopPropagation() - because it was carrying down eventListeners to clips nested within clips which I don't want. Thanks for the help...now to try and understand bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

Just attach the wedgeClickHandler to the wedge member from within the Circle class - it will receive the MouseEvent just fine, and it can access the private function directly.

Comment: If I do this - one, I don't really like that things related to wedges are in the circle class, and two - it's not recognizing the click actions on my wedges. The actual class builds a clip, and that clip is added to the circle - so I'm assuming I would need to reference the clip inside the class somehow right? But I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: @mheavers, Well your `Circle` class is instantiating a `Wedge`, it has  the responsibility of managing the `Wedge` instance; it's better then having the `Wedge` tied to upwards to a `Circle`. If you want to get more complicated, interfaces and factories are a possible solution; but that might be overkill in your case?

Comment: one - you're reacting to an event from within the wedge, but you are deactivating the *circle*.  It is perfectly alright to do so, as the wedge does not need to know anything about its parent class, and wedge is a member of circle anyway.  two - your circle should have a `private var wedge:Wedge`, otherwise it will be discarded.  Wedge, on the other hand, does not need a reference to circle, if you use event listeners.

Comment: Hey - your solution makes sense, it's just not working for me - I don't get any errors, but my listener is not registering any activity.  I am revising my question to show a little more of my actual code so you can see what's going on.

Comment: @Panupan's solution contains the correct code - don't try to make this too complicated, all you need for the click event to work is a Circle and a Wedge.  Once you've understood events and listeners, you can go ahead and add more hierarchy levels, but try to keep this first task to a minimum.

Comment: The problem is I need to listen to the click of something inside of the wedge object, not wedge itself.

Comment: That is not a problem, because MouseEvents bubble up in the display list.

Comment: I think I disabled the bubbling with stopPropagation() because Circle contains click listeners that were getting carried down to Wedge, but wedge needed to be clickable too with a different function.

Comment: OK, then do that in a clickHandler within Wedge and dispatch a bubbling custom event "wedgeClick" instead - you can listen for this and be sure it's not from within the circle.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `Circle.deactivateCircle()` because its accessibility is set to `private` and because your `Wedge` object needs to have a reference to the `Circle` object upon which you want to call the method.

Comment: You're not actually using Singleton, which is good, because it's actually an anti pattern http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/21/clean-code-talks-global-state-and-singletons/